# What app can I use to create a PowerPoint on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an iphone app that can CREATE powerpoints with normal functionality. There are many apps that can view powerpoints but not many that can create powerpoints. Office Mobile (Microsoft) can view and edit them, but not create powerpoints. Office2 Plus can create powerpoints but you gotta pay them to be able to save powerpoints. WPS office can create powerpoints. The problem is either you can't change the background color or I can't find it. I really thought that a basic feature of powerpoints. Does Prezi have an app for creating powerpoints? I would have thought there was one because they have cloud based office suites.

http://prezi.com/index/2/

I also saw there was slideshark but I haven't had a chance to test it out. How is keynote? The description of it makes it sound like its for creating powerpoints, but with a lot of extra features. The bad reviews make me not want to spend the money on it.

So what other apps can create powerpoints? Are there better apps for this?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Keynote for this. Whilst Apple haven't perfected importing all the functionality of PowerPoints yet, the exporting works flawlessly and you can create great presentations on Keynote.

Comment: or ms 365, but Keynote is unbeatable.